# Get common parent of 2 QDir

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to get the closest common parent of 2 QDir objects? So for example:

```
QDir d1("/someroot/parent/test/folder");
QDir d2("/someroot/parent/another/folder");

QDir d3 = commonParent(d1, d2);
// d3 == "/comeroot/parent/"
```

Boost.Filesystem is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const QString commonParent(const QString &path1, const QString &path2)
{
    QString ret = path2;

    while (!path1.startsWith(ret))
        ret.chop(1);

    if (ret.isEmpty())
        return ret;

    while (!ret.endsWith('/'))
        ret.chop(1);

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QDir::cdUp()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#cdUp) for this.

Working Example:

```
QString commonParent(const QDir& inputDirOne, const QDir& inputDirTwo) {
  QDir dirOne(inputDirOne);
  QString dirTwoAbsolutePath = inputDirTwo.absolutePath();
  do {
    if (dirTwoAbsolutePath.startsWith(dirOne.absolutePath()))
      return dirOne.absolutePath();
  } while(dirOne.cdUp());
  return QString();
}
```

and usage:

```
//QDir dir1("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Addins\\somefile.txt");
QDir dir1("..");
//QDir dir2("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Licenses\\Update\\1033\\License.htm");
QDir dir2("../../..");
QString result = commonParent(dir1, dir2);
qDebug() << "Common Dir : " << (result.isEmpty() ? "Does not exist" : result);
```

Did test these with a few weird paths and it works fine

Comment: I am not sure what kind of regex I would use for this, could you be a little more specific?

Comment: Yeh sorry about that, was typing from my mobile. I've updated my answer with an example. You do not even need a Regex tbh since using cdUp() on just one path is enough for your requirement with a QString::startsWith() check.

Comment: Unfortunately `cdUp()` doesn't work, as this requires the directory to already exist.